# Structuring of Solution(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, wcf, inversion-of-control

I am in the very early phases of a WinForms product rewrite, and I am trying to determine the "best" strategy for implementing a new solution structure. The current solution contains 50+ projects, and (for the most part) it contains all of the logic required to run the application.  Several of the projects do have dependencies to projects that exist in a separate "Framework" solution, but that is being replaced / modified as well.

As I said, the current solution produces a WinForms product; furthermore everything is tightly coupled together, front to back.  Additionally, we want to start offering a Web / Mobile solution in addition to/alongside our WinForms product.  Because of the desired changes, I am considering breaking this out into several separate solutions. Details follow.

- Product.Framework Solution becomes Product.Core - A shared set of assemblies containing common interfaces, enums, structs, "helpers", etc.
- Product.Windows - MVC pattern. Contains all views and business logic necessary to run the WinForms product.
- Product.Web - MVC Pattern. Contains all views and business logic necessary to run the Web product.
- Product.Services - Hostable WCF services.  Contains the public service layer that Web/Win/Mobile call into with the underlying DAL.

This is where I am looking for a sanity check:  I am planning on implementing DI/IoC in both the WinForms and Web project (I am not so much worried about injecting into the WCF services); in my mind it makes sense to have interfaces of all the concrete entities (representation of database tables) and services in the Product.Core solution. The only reference I would possibly need to Product.Services in the Web and Winforms solutions would be to register the concrete types with the container.

Does this make sense?  Is there something glaring that I have overlooked?  Thank you for any and all feedback!

Comment: This is much to vague to give you concrete hints. When I consider what you are writing this seems to be a large and important project. You should hire a professional programmer or enhance your skills. This is nothing you can learn or do with stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Luckily I am a professional programmer!  I am merely seeking feedback on what other people have done; I have worked on large applications that have used a single solution for a given product, and I have worked on projects that have used multiple solutions for a given product. They have all had their pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

The way I think about solutions is "all of the things necessary to run my program".  In your case, your WinForms application is the final step.  The goal is to be able to run the output executable from that project.  The solution, then, should consist of every project necessary in order to build that executable from scratch.  The last thing you want is to have a new developer have to checkout your source code from version control and then have to use tribal knowledge to figure out which solutions need to be built in which order and then how to tie them all together.

Now you mentioned that you may be adding some more final step applications such as a web application.  Assuming that the dependencies for your WinForms application are similar to your web application, I am of the opinion that you should just add the web application to the same solution as your WinForms application.  However, sometimes it makes sense to have a different solution for each, and then have each solution reference a similar set of projects.

One of the key things to remember is that when a project dependency is introduced, you will need to update ***all*** of your solutions to have that new dependency.  This is the primary reason why I tend to have a single solution for most things.

Don't forget, in Visual Studio you can have solution folders to help you visually manage the solution as a whole.  Also, you can utilize the build configurations and dependency tree such that building doesn't require compiling everything when you only need one final project built.  Finally, you can utilize the Set Startup Project option to switch between which final output you want to work with.

Remember, any given project can very easily be part of multiple solutions.  If you have a core set of frameworks that are used across an array of different products you can include the framework projects in each "Product" solution.  If the framework is not primarily worked on by the same team that uses it you may want to consider splitting the framework into a separate repository and only distribute the output assemblies (which would be committed into other repositories and referenced in your other solutions).

In general, my opinion is to have a single solution for everything and utilize various features of Visual Studio so managing such a large and complex solution isn't very painful.  The one thing I would advise against is having the build of one solution depend on the build output of another solution.  If you are doing this, the two projects should reside in separate repositories and the build output should be copied and committed as needed (basically treat the output as a 3rd party library).

Comment: Hi, Micah.  Solution Folders are certainly something to consider, but my concern there would be an overly elaborate folder structure that becomes tedious to navigate.  I am going to let this question sit the weekend, and if there is no better feedback I will mark this as the answer.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: In such a case, my recommendation is to separate the business into separate products, some of which may utilize the output of others.  Even if you don't plan on releasing/selling the individual business 'products' I recommend treating them as distinct and independent products that are versioned separately and do not share source code.

The process would likely be to build and "release" the Framework product and then have your WinForms product treat the Framework assemblies as it would any other third party assemblies that you would download/purchase.  This will help avoid solution coupling.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" answer here. Here is an observation from your question:
Why do you need an interface for all concrete entities? 
It appears that these are just data model classes. Unless you are looking to Mock these classes or write generic methods(or classes) that can operate on a category of classes such as all data model classes that implement an IEntity interface for instance so that you can constrain your generic method/class by the data model type.
Example:

```
public void MyGenericMethod<T>(T t) : where T:IEntity{ // do something}
```

It sounds like the refactoring / restructuring you are doing will have major impact on the business you are working for and the design/ architectural decisions made now will need to sustainable for the business as it evolves. I would highly suggest involving an architect in this process who can understand the needs and the nature of the business and come up with a game plan accordingly.